# I'm looking for a way to work offline with Google Tasks

Tags: offline, google-tasks

Is it possible to work offline with Google Tasks and then sync it back when online? My connection is not stable over here.

Please share if you know how to. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[GTasks](http://www.appbrain.com/app/gtasks/org.dayup.gtask)** allows you to work with you task list offline on your phone and then sync when you have internet as do most task managers that sync with Google Tasks.  I've never tried any of the others but I can say from experience that GTasks works well.

Answer (score 6):

[Astrid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.timsu.astrid) works fine with Google Tasks. It syncs with Google Tasks and can work offline.

Answer (score 5):

Tasks works great for me. It has a [free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.teamtasks.tasks) and [paid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.teamtasks.tasks.paid) version.

Comment: One of the most reliable Android apps I've ever used.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using **[iRT GTasks Outliner](http://www.irtgtasksoutliner.com/)** that gives you an offline outliner that syncs with GTasks. It's currently in Beta but have been quite stable for the month or so I've used it.

Answer (score 1):

Virtually any of the [apps in the Play Store which interact with Google Tasks](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=google+tasks&c=apps) will have this functionality.

That said, I have been using and quite happy with [Google Tasks Organizer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tinjasoft.tasks). (There is also a free "[Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tinjasoft.tasks_trial)" version.)